# Display Options when variant selected in Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify

I want to display options when a particular variant is selected.

Products have have 2 variants : `Normal` and `Custom`

Want to display extra line items only when `Custom` variant is selected.

Adding in the extra line items is no issue, just having trouble making them only display when the variant "Custom" is selected.

Have searched through these forus, google and the Shopify forums and cannot find a definitive answer. Would appreciate any help.

I gather it will be using JavaScripts & most of the code will be in `selectcallback` function

Comment: can you please provide a code sample of some kind: show us what you got already and then we can work with that.

Answer (score 0):

Just make that line items by default hidden (I mean display:none or visibility hidden). Then in selectCallback you need to check using if else condition that whether selected variant is "custom" or not, if it's custom then You need to make line items visible. Also in else condition you have to check if line items are visible then make them hidden again using display:none or visibility:hidden.

I hope this will work, If you have any query comment it :)